# Avoid multiple button presses during screen transition XNA WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have two classes. Screen and Button.

All different screens of my game inherit the Screen class.

Buttons are then added to the screen class and are updated(Button's update function) in the Screen's update function.

Here is the code for my Button's update.

```
foreach (TouchLocation touch in TouchPanel.GetState())
        {
            if (touch.State == TouchLocationState.Pressed)
            {
                Point point = new Point((int)touch.Position.X, (int)touch.Position.Y);
                if (rectangle.Contains(point))
                {
                    pressed = true;
                    color = Color.Red;
                }
                else
                {
                    pressed = false;
                    color = Color.White;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
```

Now here's the problem.

1. If I keep the line 
   if (touch.State == TouchLocationState.Pressed)
   then only the first button can be clicked. I also tried using TryGetPreviousLocation() which results in no button being able to be clicked.
2. If I remove the above mentioned if statement then code works for all buttons but there occur multiple button presses during screen transitions.

What I mean to say is this. Lets say I have two screens A and B. Screens A and B have two buttons P and Q respectively on exactly same location. In second case,
If P button is pressed then screen transitions to B and button Q is also pressed without the finger being lifted up.

This happens really fast and hence one cannot control it. I would like to know what can I do to allow only one press even during screen transitions. The player should not be able to press the button on the next screen without lifting up the finger and touching the screen again.

Like mentioned previously. I am calling update methods of all the buttons in the update method of the current screen.

Comment: Maybe you can try detecting `TouchLocationState.Released` instead of `TouchLocationState.Pressed`?

Answer (score 4):

Replace `TouchLocationState.pressed` with `TouchLocationState.Moved`. It works for me.

```
foreach (TouchLocation touch in touches)
    {
        if (touch.State == TouchLocationState.Moved)
        {

            if (leftRectangle.Contains((int)touch.Position.X, (int)touch.Position.Y))
            {
                spriteMove.X -= 5;
            }

            if (upRectangle.Contains((int)touch.Position.X, (int)touch.Position.Y))
            {
                spriteMove.Y -= 5;
            }

            if (rightRectangle.Contains((int)touch.Position.X, (int)touch.Position.Y))
            {
                spriteMove.X += 5;
            }

            if (downRectangle.Contains((int)touch.Position.X, (int)touch.Position.Y))
            {
                spriteMove.Y += 5;
            }
        }
    }
```